# casting int[] to char[] does not work properly

Tags: java, arrays, casting, char, integer

// EDITED: Sorry, I did not paste an important code. I edited the post with the rest of code.

I have a problem with casting Array of Integers to Array of Characters. Everything compiles, but there are no numbers after casting.

Code:

```
 plik1 = new Scanner(new File("plik1.txt"));

String line1 = plik1.nextLine();
String line2 = plik1.nextLine();

line1.trim();
line2.trim();

String[] numberArray1 = line1.split(" ");
String[] numberArray2 = line2.split(" ");

int length_line1 = numberArray1.length;
int length_line2 = numberArray2.length;

int buffer1[] = new int[length_line1];
int buffer2[] = new int[length_line2];

for(j=0; j<buffer1.length; j++) {
    buffer1[j] = Integer.valueOf(numberArray1[j]);
}

for(j=0; j<buffer2.length; j++) {
    buffer2[j] = Integer.valueOf(numberArray2[j]);
}

char[] buffer11 = new char[buffer1.length];
    char[] buffer22= new char[buffer2.length]; 

    for(j=0; j<buffer1.length; j++) {
        char number = (char) buffer1[j];
        buffer11[j] = number;
    }

    for(j=0; j<buffer2.length; j++) {
        char number = (char) buffer2[j];
        buffer22[j] = number;
    }

    for(j=0; j<buffer11.length; j++)
    System.out.print(buffer11[j] + " ");

    System.out.println();

    for(j=0; j<buffer22.length; j++) 
    System.out.print(buffer22[j] + " ");
```

Here is, what print function shows:

```
      7   +  Z  X  
      B  $ +  N X
```

How to solve it?

Comment: i think your print function prints only the strings, not the integer arrays

Comment: I don't see any array of characters.

Comment: Where is the char array?
What is you input?

Comment: so you print the chars as i said, why did you expect integer to be printed?

Comment: I want to include Integers in Char Array. How can I do it?
I have to call another funtion with char Array including Integers as parametr...
Maybe there is another way to take numbers from file and put them into char Array?

Comment: Looks like it's working to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you do

```
char number = (char) buffer1[j];
```

you actually put the integer value in the `char`, but char with a value of, let's say 43, is the "+" plus, according to the [ascii table](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:ASCII-Table-wide.svg), and that's why you get the output you are talking about.

i'll give you an example:

let's say `plik1.txt` contains

```
45, 66
46, 67
```

then after your reading `numberArray1` and `numberArray2` contains

```
["45", "66"]
["46", "67"]
```

and then `buffer1` and `buffer2` contains

```
[45, 66]
[46, 67]
```

now `buffer11` and `buffer22` will contain the save thing, but when you try to print them, java will print the ASCII sign corresponding with this number, meaning:

```
- B
. C
```

so, for conclusion, your "casting int[] to char[]" works perfectly, it's just you thought it'll do something else

Comment: I want to include Integers in Char Array. How can I do it? I have to call another funtion with char Array including Integers as parametr... Maybe there is another way to take numbers from file and put them into char Array?

I tried to put Integers from file to String and then call function toCharArray(); but suppose I have a 88 number, when I call the function I recieve 8, 8... and I had no idea, how to solve it. Also white spaces were included.

Comment: @csal this an A-B problem. please explain why do you need integer in char in the first place

Comment: Oh, I understand. So how can I print it to recieve numbers? Is it possible? :)

Comment: I have a function with two char[] as parameters. My file include two lines with Integers. I have to take these numbers from file and somehow put them to two char[] Arrays to call the function. :)

Comment: @csal you can print them simply by writing System.out.print(buffer2[j] + " ");

Comment: I did it. Look:
 for(j=0; j<buffer11.length; j++)
 System.out.print(buffer11[j] + " ");

But it still prints weird signs...

Comment: @csal no, i said System.out.print(buffer2[j] + " "); no "22". same goes for buffer1, not 11